# Load jquery from external html using load then detach current div and load it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, load

Okay.. the scenario is

index.html

```
<body>
<button class="a"> loading file home2.html #home2</button>
<button class="b"> loading file index.html #home</button>
<section id ="a">
  <div id="home">
    blah blah blah
  </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

and 2nd file

home2.html

```
<div id="home2">
    bleh bleh bleh
</div>
```

when i click on button 1, i want to load all content #home2 in home2.html into index.html.
i used .load() method. then after load #home2 from home2.html i want to detach #home (not just fadeOut() or hide(). but when i click button2 to load #home again, all of js inside #home not working. anyone help me ?

Comment: what js inside of #home? you are expecting people to fix your js without ever seeing your js

Answer (score 0):

This is partly a guess as you didn't provide enough information... but I believe it's a pretty good guess.

The problem is probably that you are setting binds to elements... then destroying and recreating the elements and expecting the binds to still be there. It doesn't work this way... you either have to create the binds after content is made or use delegation.

Here is an example of what I believe represents what you have:

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/aCRBuNldUcf3LONK0JEO?p=preview) - if you click on "blah blah blah" it will give an alert the first time... but not after swapping content.

```
  var originalContent = $("#a").html();
  $(".a").click(function() {
    $("#a").load("home2.html");
  });
  $(".b").click(function() {
    $("#a").html(originalContent);
  });
  $("#home").click(function() {
    alert("#home clicked");
  });
  $("#home2").click(function() {
    alert("#home2 clicked");
  });
```

To fix it with delegation, you can delegate from the `#a` element like this:

[PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/wwFHNBJSNghEpknDdxyG?p=preview) - Notice it will work now no matter how many times you change the content..

```
  var originalContent = $("#a").html();
  $(".a").click(function() {
    $("#a").load("home2.html");
  });
  $(".b").click(function() {
    $("#a").html(originalContent);
  });
  $("#a").on("click", "#home", function() { //delegating from #a
    alert("#home clicked");
  });
  $("#a").on("click", "#home2", function() {
    alert("#home2 clicked");
  });
```